# FileMaker: Find Records Based on the Contents of Records in a Related Table?

Tags: find, global, portal, filemaker

I have a layout that contains a portal.  The portal shows rows which contain dates. The master table (the "one" table in the "one-to-many" relationship) has two global fields, gStartDate and gEndDate.

I would like to do a find that would select all the records in the master table, that have rows in the related table, that fall within these two dates.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the best one will depend on your particular database:

### Simple Relationship

If the relationship is set up such that

```
mastertable::index -----< portaltable::mastertableIndex
```

Then you can simply perform a date range find in the portal on the master table by hand or by script. This would look like:

```
1/1/2013...12/31/2013
```

in the portal's date field, assuming you are in the U.S.

When you perform the find, the found set of master records, will all contain a portal record in that date range.

### Complex Relationship

You can also set up a more complex relationship, as you indicated with your own answer. That relationship would look like this:

```
mastertable::index       = portaltable::mastertableIndex
mastertable::gStartDate <= portaltable::date
mastertable::gEndDate   >= portaltable::date
```

If you use that relationship, you can enter Find mode, put an `*` into the date field of the portal, and perform the Find. This will, again, find all master records that have dates that fall within the range.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the correct way is to put the filter criteria (in this case, the date range) into the relationship between the two tables.  I previously had it in the portal filter. Once it's in the relationship, you can add a calculated field to the master table to count the number of related fields in that date range. Then it's easy to do a find for when that calculated field > 0.

Comment: Performing finds on a calculation field that isn't stored can have some pretty significant performance consequences. For speed, you would be better off finding the date range directly. My answer gives two examples of how to do so.